# perl install DBD::mysql failed on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, perl

I have installed the latest mysql database on my ubuntu 20.04 laptop.

Next I tried to install all the perl modules I need to write Perl scripts to access my mysql database.
I started a "sudo -i" session from which I ran the "cpanb" command

I successfully used cpan to install the DBI module

However when I attempted to install the DBD::mysql module it failed.

The last part of the output was as follows :

```
Configuring D/DV/DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 89.

Cannot find the file 'mysql_config'! Your execution PATH doesn't seem
not contain the path to mysql_config. Resorting to guessed values!


PLEASE NOTE:

For 'make test' to run properly, you must ensure that the
database user 'root' can connect to your MySQL server
and has the proper privileges that these tests require such
as 'drop table', 'create table', 'drop procedure', 'create procedure'
as well as others.

mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 's3kr1t';

You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:

perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 603.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located
Failed to determine directory of mysql.h. Use

  perl Makefile.PL --cflags=-I<dir>

to set this directory. For details see DBD::mysql::INSTALL,
section "C Compiler flags" or type

  perl Makefile.PL --help
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
  DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz               : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site' returned status 512

cpan[3]>
```

Comment: Did you install AND configure `mysqld`, the database server?

Comment: I followed the same steps I used 4 months ago on a different Linux Ubuntu 20.04 laptop which worked just fine. None of the steps referenced mysqld specifically.

My error was that I forgot one needed step for Perl mysql scriptig:
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

Answer (score 3):

After some google searching, it turns out that what I needed to do to resolve this issue was the following

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Now my Perl based MySQL scripts seem to be working just fine.